# How to add data to an ellipse QT

Tags: c++, qt

I have a function in which i draw an ellipse to a scene which is on a QGraphicsView, in another function i have a click event that checks if you have clicked the same XY as the ellipse and then iterates over a map to see if that XY is assigned to a specific object if it is that Object is returned

however iv been looking into finding a way so that when an ellipse is clicked it just has data bound to it instead of having to search the xy etc to find the data

i found the function setdata which allows you to assign data to an item however seeing as my function simply draws and adds data i have no idea how to actully extract the data thats cound to it, i have a feeling its because i need to add an item which is a scene and the data should be bound to the item but i dont know how thats done and searching the docs hasnt given me any answers

heres my function

```
void GUI::paintDot(double x, double y, double Id)
{
    // Decalre a QPen for Painting dots
    QPen pen;

    // set the pen colour
    pen.setColor(Qt::white);

    if(x < m_height && y < m_width)
    {
        // Add ellipse at the x y position passed in
        scene2->addEllipse(x, y, 1.5, 1.5, pen, QBrush(Qt::SolidPattern))->setData(0, Id);
    }
}
```

0 being just an arbitrary key value which will need to change to something that actually represents a key value, but for the sake of this example its fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not showing the code **where** you are trying to get the data back (eg, in a event handler that caches a mouse press or something).  So I'm not positive what your issue actually is, but it should be as simple as:

```
QVariant v = ellipseObject->data(0);
```

And then you extract your value out of that depending on the datatype you put in.  In your case, you put in a double:

```
 double d = v.toDouble();
```

(and obviously those two lines could be combined without the need for variable `v`)